# How can I pass controller scope to a partial html file?

Tags: html, angularjs, ajax

This is my main HTML file.

```
<div ng-controller="filterController">
    <div class="quick-view" id="quickview" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-bar" 
                                  ng-click="quickView(quickview)"><i class="fa fa-eye">
                                                      </i><span>Quick View</span></div>
</div>
```

This is my controller.js file

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('filterController', function($scope) {
    $scope.quickView = function quickView(id){  
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'assets/external/_modal.html',
            data: id,
            success: function (data) {
                // Create HTML element with loaded data   
                $('body').append(data); 
                console.log('body append');
            },
            error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,exception){console.log('Exception:'+exception);}
            });      
    }
    $scope.venue = "India";
}
```

This is _modal.html

```
<div ng-controller="filterController">
    <p>Hi. I live in {{venue}}</p>
</div>
```

How can I pass the controller scope to the external file _modal.html so that "I live in India" gets displayed instead of "I live in {{venue}}"?

Comment: Why do you work like this? jQuery's ajax, appending dom elements to the body?? Angularjs is just an excuse here, this is palin jQuery

Comment: why $.ajax ? we don't need .. Try like my ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try angularjs way. Use uib modal. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope,$uibModal, $log, $document) {
  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
  $scope.Venue = "India"; // declare venue

  $scope.open = function (size, parentSelector) {
    var parentElem = parentSelector ? 
      angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      appendTo: parentElem,
      resolve: {
        values: function () {
          return $scope.Venue; //we are passing venue as values
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function () {
      $scope.msg = "Submitted";
      $scope.suc = true; 
    }, function(error) {
      $scope.msg = 'Cancelled';
      $scope.suc = false; 
    });
  };
});


angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope,$uibModalInstance, values) { // inject that resolved values
 $scope.Venue= values; // we are getting & initialize venue from values
  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close('ok');
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl" class="modal-demo">
    
   <br> 
<form name="form" novalidate>
 Type your venue :  <input type="text" style="width:200px" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="Venue" required><br>
   <button type="button" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="form.$valid && open()">See Venue</button>
</form><br>
    <p ng-hide="!msg" class="alert" ng-class="{'alert-success':suc, 'alert-danger':!suc}">{{msg}}</p>
    
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Your Details</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
           
            <p>The venue is <b>{{Venue }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer (Upvoted), but I suggest that you include more explanations about what you did and perhaps a link to the official documentation the help the OP learn more about native modals

Comment: Yep. @AlonEitan

Comment: @manikandan-velayutham If I were to put the open function in a service, and inject that service to a controller, how can i pass controller data to the 'open' function? I am able to get the controller data inside the service, but I'm not able to pass that data as a parameter along with( size, parentSelector) to 'open' function.

Comment: When I tried to display that parameter inside open function it gives undefined.

Comment: Consoling the values returned by resolve inside the ModalInstanceCtrl gives Object {result: d, opened: d, closed: d, rendered: d, close: function…} instead of the actual returned object.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to join the chat.

Comment: If possible add plunkr or snipt etc.